# Connect to "onCompleted" signal of component from js code

Tags: signals, qml, components

I have a main window with a stack view allowing other components to push components on the stack. Every component has a property "title" which defines the title in the appBar. Here is the code how I want it (it does not work):

```
function pushPage(page) {
    stackView.push(page);
    if (page.status === Component.Ready) {
       titleLabel.text = stackView.get(stackView.depth-1).title;
    }
    page.onCompleted: {//This does not work
        titleLabel.text = stackView.get(stackView.depth-1).title;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it can happen that a component is not yet loaded when it is pushed. So "title" must be set when the component has finished loading. But how can I connect to the "onCompleted" signal of the component from imperative code? The syntax in my example does not work.

Comment: Not an answer to the question you asked, but why don't you just do `text: stackView.currentItem.title` in your title label ?
Doing things declaratively is much more preferred than doing it imperatively.

Comment: Oh, that is nice. I did not know that it was possible. I will do it that way.